# Can we use special method in python on "set","list" and "tuple"?

Tags: python

I tried the following

```
class Book():
    
    def __init__(self, title, author,pages):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.pages = pages
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.author}"
    
    def __int__(self):
        return self.pages
    
    def __list__(self):
        return (self.title,self.author,self.pages)
```

and then ran

```
b = Book('Hero','Jose',205)
list(b)
```

I got this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-3361f11725ee> in <module>
----> 1 tuple(b)

TypeError: 'Book' object is not iterable
```

Comment: No, that isn't how those constructors work. They accept *iterables*. To make an object iterable, you must implement it's `__iter__` method. `__list__` is not a special method. The special methods are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 3):

`list` works by iterating over the object, you can change the `__list__` method to this

```py
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.title
    yield self.author
    yield self.pages
```